# Bootstrap tooltip inside ag-grid cell showing partially

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ag-grid

I am trying to show bootstrap tooltip in ag-grid cell on hover. Issue is it's showing up partially while part of the tooltip is behind the next column cell. I tried setting z-index for tooltip. But still not able to succeed. Kindly help.
[image]

Comment: Can you have a look at once to my query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691754/angular-ag-grid-attach-class-to-grouped-rows-cell-based-on-validation-of-other-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS tooltips, which will work inside agGrid cells. Please take a look at this plnkr: [tooltip in agGrid cell](https://plnkr.co/edit/kyE4JZ?p=preview)

```
[data-tooltip]:before {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks C.O.G! I resolved it by giving div.tooltip{
position:fixed;
}. Can you please explain me how position:fixed makes it work?

Comment: @codechimp position fixed will place it based on the window x and y values rather the wrapper element

Answer (score 4):

In ngx-bootstrap documentation:

> When you have some styles on a parent element that interfere with a tooltip, you’ll want to specify a container="body" so that the tooltip’s HTML will be appended to body. This will help to avoid rendering problems in more complex components (like our input groups, button groups, etc) or inside elements with overflow: hidden

You can use the attribute `container="body"` to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this one by adding the following CSS

```
[col-id=health].ag-column-hover: {
    overflow: visible
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for angular5+ with ng-bootstrap use  **container="body"**

Answer (score 0):

Try using `tooltip-append-to-body="true"` option for bootstrap tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked, Add below css to your file.
All credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46007051/16456741

```
.ag-sparkline-tooltip {
        position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32855536)